# What is this blue USB device with an orange tongue?

Tags: usb

Found this device outside an elementary school, trying to identify and return to owner.

When it is plugged into a Mac (because I'm straight crazy) it prompts a new unknown keyboard dialogue.

Item is plastic, blue in color, and roughly key-shaped. The narrow end of it is a small USB dongle that has an orange 'tongue' inside. I am not sure what orange color designates on USB.

Text on the sides of the metal:

Back side:

- CAN ICES-3(B)/NMB-3(B)
- AMAZON EU L-1855
- LUXEMBOURG
- D33724 RoHS

Left Side:

- G3Q0W907
- 93120H1K

Right Side:

- MODEL NO. U05U83
- ASSEMBLED IN USA

[image: Blue plastic key-shape]
[image: Bottom]
[image: Left]
[image: Top]
[image: Right]
[image: Front]

Comment: Why would you wanna know specifically which USB stick it is? Just write a note: "I found a blue usb key, email me at david@dillard.com" and stick it on the door. The files on it may give you a clue to who its owner is. It probably dirt cheap.

Comment: no files- some kind of receiver

Comment: What device shows up in Device Manager when you plug it in?

Comment: The PC (mac) only prompts an unknown keyboard dialogue, similar to when I attach a presentation remote

Comment: @Gantendo: “…and stick it on the door.” Whose door and what door? That is the problem. Just because someone found something in front of a building does not mean that thing belongs to the owner of the building. Knowing now that this is an Amazon employee ID security key what would an elementary school do with it?

Comment: @Gantendo also definitely don't go around sticking found USB devices in your systems. You don't know what it could do. People are known to drop USB devices containing malware deliberately.

Comment: I would like to emphasize that you should NEVER plug in an unknown USB drive into your machine. Dropping an infected USB drive in front of a building is a classic way of starting a cyberattack. It is not unfathomable that attackers could compromise an entire district's educational IT system, just because one teacher plugged in such a USB drive into their computer. Please don't do this.

Comment: @Gantendo that's a very risky advice. It could be malicious: e.g. by assuming keyboard and mouse identity, it can control your computer. Or it could be a [USBKill](https://usbkill.com/) :-D.

Comment: @Edheldil I have a collection of BadUSBs. I do not own a USBkiller but I know what they look like. Assuming a randomly found USB stick is malicious is like assuming all water bottles are poisoned. Sure, there may be some bottled water out there that is poisoned. But the chance of encountering a poisoned water bottle when thirsty is minute. Isn't "Auto Play" disabled on Win10 machines by default nowadays? USB flash drives are a billion dollar market. USBkillers & BadUSBs are not.

Comment: @Gantendo I think the idea is not to make it an absolute rule, but rather to encourage people who have less security awareness to be careful. The same way I was told by my parents as a toddler to not open the door to strangers (I was actually surprised when I noticed how many children would actually listen to strangers telling them to follow them out of the house). Chances are it's just the delivery guy rather than someone dangerous (although it depends where you live). But since I was a toddler, I didn't have their level of awareness. It doesn't apply to you since you're more knowledgeable.

Comment: @Gantendo I would also not drink from a random water bottle I found on the street (unless there is not other water nearby and I'm near dying from thirst).

Comment: For future reference, orange is generally only used for accent coloring on USB devices. On USB hosts, it’s a non-standard color used to indicate some variant USB port (most that I’ve come across use it to indicate either an ‘always-on’ port, or an older pre USB-PD high-power port).

Comment: Maybe its a cultural difference. I've drank from random creeks and I've played outside all day. Back in my day stranger danger wasn't a thing. Scaring people who aren't supernerds is, in my view, often counterproductive. It makes them call me all the time. My strategy is to teach them to make backups. It took me a while to find the exact model, but I knew this wasn't a BadUSB/USBkiller. Now that we know its a security key the chances someone has modded it to be "bad" are even slimmer Basically nonexistent. 70 year olds own handfuls of USBsticks, but the market for BadUSBs/USBkillers is tiny.

Comment: Maybe tweet to @AmazonHelp? before directly mailing to Amazon. It is good idea to contact them who knows thy have different procedure?

Comment: @Gantendo when we're talking about random found USB drives, the cost/benefit of plugging them in just doesn't work out.  Best case scenario, you end up with a new-to-you drive worth $5-$10.  It's not likely it has malware, but it it does the cost is high.  So yeah, most people's default choice should be destroying the thing rather than chasing that $10 windfall.  It's not a cultural divide, it's simple cost/benefit analysis.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It’s an Amazon security token: https://fccid.io/RR-E48-U05U83

> Company:  Amazon Fulfillment Service Inc.
> Device Name:  Security Doken
> Model:    U05U83

So mail it to Amazon. A delivery driver probably lost it.

Comment: Maybe tweet to @AmazonHelp?

Comment: Adding to the above: before directly mailing to Amazon (what Amazon? retail/cloud/HQ | where? returns/HQ/operations). It is good idea to contact them who knows thy have different procedure?

Comment: TBH if the driver has already reported it as lost then it will probably be blacklisted from the network anyway and Amazon won't care about it anymore. Even if they take it back it will only be to dispose of it. At least, that would be the sensible thing to do from their point of view.

Comment: Also according to the answer from @Gantendo it appears that they should have a backup key. Presumably the issue of lost tokens is common enough for them to give 2 whenever the token is required.

Comment: Is "Security **D**oken" a typo, or some sort of brand name?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms - Judging by the number of times it appears in the link, I'd guess it's a name.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms it's a portmanteau of Dongle and Token.

Comment: Mail it to amazon ?  They're a business, not a charity.  Contact them and let them send you something to post it back in prepaid if they want it.

Answer (score 43):

According to [this page](https://firstaid.amazon-corp.com/vnho/win/insert-sec-key) it is a Zukey which is security key.

> “Security keys help keep Amazon’s data safe. You’ll use your security key to connect to internal services and the Amazon virtual private network (VPN). There are several types of security keys at Amazon, but they all have the same features.”

[image: Image showing all the different kinds of security keys Amazon uses.]

Answer (score 3):

NEVER plugin a USB you found laying somewhere into a computer that is important. USBs could have malicious firmware that infects your computer the moment you plug it in. This is equally accurate for [USB cables](https://www.vice.com/en/article/evj4qw/these-iphone-lightning-cables-will-hack-your-computer). Anything with a USB interface is susceptible.

On another note, the colour. You may be familiar with black and blue plugs and wonder what orange means? It is up to the manufacturer to decide because USB port and connector colours are [not enforced in the USB specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Colors) and manufacturers can color them as they wish.

It appears they decided to colour all their Zukey's orange.

Comment: Also it may be "pendrive" which accumulates power and discharges instantly making computer motherboard useless. This is second reason not to plugin unknown devices into USB port.

Answer (score -2):

Two options:

1. it's either a Zukey (mentioned in the other answers; it will act as a keyboard and "type" a one-time password/passphrase for the user)

or

2. it's more like a USB Rubber Ducky, disguised as a Zukey. Such devices will also act like a USB keyboard and send useful keystrokes and/or mouse movements to the computer. More advanced devices can be remotely controlled.

"Useful keystrokes" (which can be sent a few seconds, minutes, hors after the device has been plugged in) can be commands to take over the machine, open an SSH tunnel or other remote network control connection, download or even type in malware, do funny things to annoy you - or just jiggle the mouse pointer so the machine will never activate the screen saver/screen lock.

One of the most popular ways to deliver such a "trojan horse" into some company's computer's USB port is by dropping them on the parking lot. Or, if you are a visitor or HVAP maintenance person who is allowed temporary access to a data center, you can plug it in yourself when your guard is distracted.

These things can also be used for non-malicious activities, like performing repetitive work which cannot be otherwise automated.

However, the stuff inside your device does not looks one of these "Rubber Ducky" or Arduino Leonardo-based devices.

Comment: Ah- sending keystrokes. Thats a clever way. Now Im thinking what else can you plug into a usb port that can do stuff. Imagine it disguises itself as a usb hub, then it can pretend to be multiple different devices plugged into a usb hub and it won't be limited to being just being a keyboard. It can now be a keyboard AND a mouse! And an ethernet port, and a printer, and maybe a monitor but Im not sure, and a usb stick, and who knows what else. What about those usb connected GPUs. And you do sensitive operations on GPUs and all the sudden this rogue GPU pops up and logs your program execution.